# Python Scraper creates ValueError fault when scraping more than 2 cells in sheet

Tags: python, web-scraping

***Edit 1*** I have found where the error seems to be occuring, but not sure what is causing the break.

Text from cell 1 = 1 2 FUGE ST HIGHETT VIC 3190
returns **https://www.realestate.com.au/property-unit-vic-highett-126564142**

Text from cell 2 = 1 18 FERNCROFT AVE MALVERN EAST VIC 3145

which causes a break in the code. The only difference in the two entries, is the second one has 8 strings instead of 7, I tested this across a huge range of addresses, if it has 7 it works, if it has 8 - it fails. Can anyone see in the below code what would be causing a string count to cause errors like this? and is there a way to add an exception? It's got me pulling my hair out now.

***End Edit 1***

I have a weird error occurring when running a scraper that will scrape 3 records from an excel sheet, but errors out on anything above 3 rows. It's a bit of a head scratcher, as i have tried changing the data in the 2 cells to different URL's and its always the same - if there are 2 cells or less it will scrape and close successfully - if there are 2 plus rows - it will stop on the 3rd cell and error out with the following error

```
File "C:\Python27\projects\REA_UN\REA_UNIQUEID\2.py", line 32, in <module>
  (Unique_ID,) = (x for x in tree.xpath('//a[@class="property-value__link--
   muted rui-button-brand property-value__btn-listing"]/@href'))
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I have tried the following:

-Checked 20 different URL's to see if there is a variable in the source

-Rebuilt code line by line to see if there is anything glitchy

-Removed the Panda modifier and run straight from reading

Nothing has worked and is constantly throwing out the same error - this leads me to believe there is something up with how it is reading the list itself, but not 100% sure on that....

For test purposes this is what is in the excel sheet

```
1 10 OAK ST PASCOE VALE VIC 3044
1 1149 NEPEAN HWY HIGHETT VIC 3190
1 10 OAK ST PASCOE VALE VIC 3044
1 1149 NEPEAN HWY HIGHETT VIC 3190
1 10 OAK ST PASCOE VALE VIC 3044
1 1149 NEPEAN HWY HIGHETT VIC 3190
```

Which should return

```
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-townhouse-vic-highett-126589490
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-malvern-126575878
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-townhouse-vic-highett-126589490
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-malvern-126575878
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-townhouse-vic-highett-126589490
http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-vic-malvern-126575878
```

How ever it will only return the top 2 if there are 2 cells or less in the sheet

Full code below:

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
from lxml import html

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Python27\Projects\REA_UNIQUE_ID\\Conversion_List.xlsx", sheetname="DNC")
dnc = df['Property']
dnc_list = list(dnc)
url_base = "https://www.realestate.com.au/property/"
URL_LIST = []

for nd in dnc_list:
    nd = nd.strip()
    nd = nd.lower()
    nd = nd.replace(" ", "-")
    URL_LIST.append(url_base + nd)

text2search = '''The information provided'''

with open('REA_ID.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),

        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (Unique_ID,) = (x for x in tree.xpath('//a[@class="property-value__link--muted rui-button-brand property-value__btn-listing"]/@href'))
            writer.writerow([title, Unique_ID])
```

Any ideas/help is appreciated as it's very odd!